# Problems initializing the Rumble player

Tags: javascript, media-player, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am testing the **Rumble player** in an application developed in Blazor. The player is embedded using a div as explained in the [documentation](https://www.rumbleplayer.com/developers/Rumble-Player-API.html). I have noticed that sometimes the player does not initialize. I have debugged the initialization function they propose in the documentation and there are times when the `if(r[b]._.length==1)` condition is not met.  Can you give me an idea of what is happening.

This is the function that configures the Rumble player, at the time it should be displayed. This function is invoked at the initialization of the Blazor component that displays the video.

```
function configRumble(videoSrc) {
try {

    var options = {
        video: videoSrc,
        div: 'video-content',
        ia: 1,
        api: function (api) {
            registerEventsRumble(api);
        }
    };

    Rumble("play", options);
} catch (e) {
    errorTrack(e.message, "config_rumble.js", "configRumble");
}
```

}

Comment: say, do you have any idea how to create a token in Rumble ? seems to be impossible and there's no videos / help about it, it's crazy